# Best way of accessing inner Observables in RxSwift?

Tags: swift, rx-swift

So I have a `AddToDoViewModelInput` object that stores multiple `Observable<T>` values.  I'd like to be able to access all of the observable values at once so that I can copy their contents into a `AddItemViewControllerProperties` object.  This object stores non-observable data.  This object will eventually get converted into a `AddToDoViewModelOutput` object.  So basically I have:

```
AddToDoViewModelInput -> AddItemViewControllerProperties -> AddToDoViewModelOutput
```

The `AddToDoViewModelInput` and `AddToDoViewModelOutput` objects contain observables while `AddItemViewControllerProperties` does not contain observables.

Currently, I am using `combineLatest` to combine the observables inside of `AddToDoViewModelInput` and in my closure passed to `combineLatest` I am creating an `AddItemViewControllerProperties` object and returning it.

I'm not sure if using `combineLatest` in this way is correct or not.  I thought that I remember that `combineLatest` will fire if **any** of the observables emit events, so in my case this may not be what I want.
Is there an existing pattern or best practice that I can follow to implement this correctly?

```
let disposeBag = DisposeBag()

struct AddToDoViewModelInput {
    let day: Observable<Int>
    let name: Observable<String>
}

struct AddItemViewControllerProperties {
    let dayOfTheWeek: Int?
    let name: String
}

struct AddToDoViewModelOutput {
    let message: Observable<String>
}

let input = AddToDoViewModelInput(
    day: Observable.of(2),
    name: Observable.of("Tuesday")
)

let propertiesObs: Observable<AddItemViewControllerProperties> = 
  Observable.combineLatest(input.name, input.day)
{
    (name, day) in
    return AddItemViewControllerProperties(dayOfTheWeek: day, name: name)
}

let messageObs: Observable<String> = propertiesObs.map{ properties in
    return "For day #\(properties.dayOfTheWeek!) the name is \(properties.name)"
}

messageObs
    .debug("messageObs")
    .subscribe(onNext: { message in print(message) })
    .disposed(by: disposeBag)

let output = AddToDoViewModelOutput(message: messageObs)
}
```

Comment: Maybe you're just looking for the `zip` operator then ! This will fire when all observables have fired an event. See http://reactivex.io/documentation/operators/zip.html

Comment: A very recognizable situation indeed ;) I solved it with my own framework which I successfully use ever since in my projects - https://github.com/maxvol/RaspSwift

Comment: thanks!  the `zip` operator was what I needed.